# 2 dimmers in one box, one with ground capped

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, dimmer-switch

I have a box with 2 dimmers and one on/off switch.  One dimmer (right dimmer in the picture) has the ground connected to the bare copper wire in the ground box.  The left dimmer has the ground wire capped (looks blue).  This was done by an electrician.
Is it OK to have one of the ground wires capped?
This dimmer recently failed.  I replaced it and capped the ground the same way and it works.  Just want to make sure it's safe and correct.
Thanks.[image: box with 2 dimmers]

Answer (score 2):

Updated based on OP's comment that this is a **Leviton RNL06-TW**.

There are three different things going on here:

- Green ground - Any green ground wire (i.e., coming out of a switch, receptacle, timer, etc.) should be grounded properly. That can be either to another ground wire or to the metal box (assuming the metal box is itself properly grounded).
- Generally speaking, all switches should be grounded. **They can be grounded via the yoke**, as long as they are designed to be installed that way, which is normally the case with a metal plate/yoke as in your switches, and as long as they are installed in properly grounded metal boxes with nothing in between the yoke and the box, again as appears to be the case here.
- Wires that are *not* bare copper or green or green/yellow are **not** ground. If any of those are not needed then they should be capped unless the instructions say otherwise. A typical example is a traveler/communication wire used if a timer is installed in a multi-switch (e.g., 3-way or 4-way switch) configuration.

In this case, the <s>blue</s> green wire should be combined in a wire nut with the other ground wires. Not strictly needed for grounding thanks to the metal yoke + metal box, but definitely best practice.

Comment: Agree with this.  Sometimes colors vary a bit in shade, but a green ground would never be so discolored that it looked blue.  The blue would be a traveller.  Also, just for the askers benefit... The green screw or ground wire is almost never needed for a device or switch to function.  You may never notice a problem, so people assume it's not important, but the ground wire should _always_ be used for safety reasons.  They come into play when there is an electrical fault, and then you _really_ want it to be there and working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments.  Much appreciated!  I can assure you that the wire is green.  It's just a different shade and the lighting makes it look blue.  Is my best bet a grounding clip?  I don't see a yoke or any grounding screws in the box.

Comment: Well, it looks blue to me, and there is a green wire on the other switch and the difference is pretty clear. As far as the yoke - that is the fancy term for the part of the switch that the screw goes through to attach to the box - in both of your switches it is the metal front plate. I wouldn't expect to see any grounding screws - if they supply a ground wire then the expectation is that you would connect it with a wire nut. As far as the *blue* wire, what is the make/model # of the dimmer so we can check the directions?

Comment: Thanks again.  The model is Leviton RNL06-TW
https://www.amazon.com/Leviton-R00-RNL06-0TW-Dimmer-White-Almond/dp/B0787VDDRM
The instructions refer to the "Green dimmer ground lead".

Comment: Interesting. Cause it sure looks blue. But based on the model, it is green/ground and there is a slightly different 3-way model which uses red for the travelers.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could connect it with the other ground wire in the same wire nut, but will do that or attach it to the yoke.  Thanks again to everyone for the timely advice.

Comment: You can't just "attach it to the yoke". The yoke is screwed to the box - a wire thrown into the middle will just mess things up. You either put it in the wire nut (which should be just fine) or a new wire nut (to replace the old one) or connect it to a ground screw to attach it directly to the box.

Comment: If you connect the ground wire to the other grounds before working on anything else, then the metal plate on the front of the switch is grounded even when the switch is unmounted and you're working on its live conductors.  A small added safety margin that perhaps the original installer of this switch couldn't be bothered with.  If the box were plastic it would be essential.  In your situation, it's ok to do it the way it was done, though not perfect, and it avoids untwisting and retwisting a bunch of wires that ain't broke.  What I would do is untwist them and reconnect them with a lever nut.